# best tool to handle big data and data visualization

Tags: data-visualization, bigdata, data-analysis

I'm currently doing (starting) my project on big data and data visualization. So please let me know if there any the best software to handle big data and data visualization i.e for data analysis.

Comment: What data? What analysis? What language? You have to be more specific,

Comment: I have real world data of customer from mobile communication. And I'm looking forward to software for data visualization...

Comment: No sure it fits, read the FAQ there, but if it does - there could be great answer in [CrossValidated.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I read faq before posting this question and I think this question is under `software tools commonly used by programmers` so I ask here... Thanks for link of crossValidates.ne ... I'll ask my other question related to data mining on there...

Comment: NP here, did not vote to close or anything ,just referencing to other SE site which could be better for these questions because it is more focused - and thus your question will most likely be read by a larger number of data mining experts.

Comment: @amit I agreed with you... As said truly I don't know about that site before posting this question... Now I know... I'll follow it from now as I am doing project on data mining i.e. lots of problem remaining to face...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tableau is a very good software.

However, if your are interested in Open Software, you can try Gephi, Mondrian, R-Project, and Google Refine (data cleaning).

Answer (score 2):

I would say Start with learning about What is Big Data? what are various data visualization Tools out there.

There are lot's of tools and you have lot's of choices. Do you use Excel? Excel can do data visualization too. Want something more out of Excel? Try out Power View in Excel 2013 (beta). Want more? Look at Softwares out there. Like R, Tableau and list goes on...

I would suggest you to give this free short ebook a read: http://parasdoshi.com/2012/05/18/want-to-learn-about-bigdata-read-oreillys-book-planning-for-bigdata/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, Thanks. Though the question was closed because it was too broad for SO. I hope you got to know the SO rules and also, I hope the resource would be good starting for you to learn and come back with questions that are answerable on SO. Good luck!